# Alert dialog doesn't appear in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Trying to set a done list for todo app. I am trying to make a dialog show when clicked on button, after that dialog doesn't appear.

```
showdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(todo.this);
                builder.setAdapter(itemdone, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String strDone = itemdone.getItem(which);
                        AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(todo.this);
                        builderInner.setTitle("Done List");
                        builderInner.setMessage(strDone);
                        builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        builderInner.create().show();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Change                 `builder.show();` to                 `builder.create().show();`

Comment: Hii @Youngho your question is not to do anything with Android Studio. It is related with Android Programming. So use proper word so that other will answer more quickly. 
Happy coding. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call show on teh dialog, not on the builder. Also renamed from `builder` to `showDoneBuilder` to differentiate from the inner builder. Pulled out the inner build for readability.

```
 showdone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          AlertDialog.Builder showDoneBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(todo.this);
            showDoneBuilder.setAdapter(itemdone, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String strDone = itemdone.getItem(which);
                    showDoneListDialog(strDone);
                }
            });
            showDoneBuilder.create().show(); // THE FIX
    }
 }

 private void showDoneListDialog(String message) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builderInner = new AlertDialog.Builder(todo.this);
       builderInner.setTitle("Done List");
       builderInner.setMessage(message);
       builderInner.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.dismiss();
           }
       });
       builderInner.create().show();
}
```